# Interesting problem about a 'frictionless pool table'

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

I was looking at this mechanics problem:

[image: Mechanics question]

Looking at the first paragraph, about showing a parallel path after two bounces, I solved it as follows.  Consider this diagram:

[image]

Resolving velocity perpendicular to the first and second cushions, and using the coefficient of restitution, we have

$$
ev_1\sin{\theta} = v_2\sin{\phi} \\
ev_2\cos{\phi} = v_3\cos{\psi}
$$

Also, resolving for conservation of momentum parallel to the cushions:

$$
v_1\cos{\theta} = v_2\cos{\phi} \\
v_2\sin{\phi} = v_3\sin{\psi}
$$

Combining these, we can conclude:

$$
ev_1\sin{\theta} = v_3\sin{\psi} \\
ev_1\cos{\theta} = v_3\cos{\psi}
$$

Therefore $\tan{\theta} = \tan{\psi}$ and hence $\theta = \psi$.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas for a solution to the second paragraph (the paragraph with the puck resting at a point dividing L in the ratio z:1)? I've experimented with a couple of ways, and am pretty sure it reduces to proving that a point always exists for the first bounce that will ensure the puck hits the adjacent cushion on the second bounce.